# Do both the independent and the dependent variables need to be stationary?

Tags: regression, time-series, stationarity

For an empirical research paper I need to use stationary data, but now i'm wondering whether both the dependent variable (aex index) and the independent variables (unemployment netherlands, usdeur/ exchange rate) need to be stationary? Im working with stata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both need to be stationary. Otherwise, the one that is nonstationary would diverge while the other would revert to its mean, so there could not be an equality between them plus a stationary error term.